# Why is http or https not showing in the dropdown in the binding menu

Tags: windows-services

I have installed IIS manager on the windows server 2022, when I am trying to add a website on IIS manager there is no binding with http or https. Can you suggest me why this is not showing on my IIS manager?

I followed the following steps:
Installed IIs manager on windows server from service manager -> Created a build file for the app of my project -> when I try to add a website in the sites list from the App in IIS the bindings are not available which is odd.

I have the admin rights for the server and also able to restart the IIS manager through windows powershell as well. Even by restarting didn't help me in updating the IIS. I am not sure if we can edit the config files for the IIS on the server (if applicable), as I am the admin I think I shold be have the option to edit the config files too.

I tried adding multiple features in Service manager, updated and restated IIS manager too, but that didn't work. I even did a complete delete and adding back of IIS manager and this is running on a windows server 2022 and on a on premise servers. Can anyone suggest me why these are not showing and only ftp shows up in the binding list?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RjKK.png)